# Filter an array of hashes Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[
   [0] {
    "10:45" => 40,
    "11:00" => 40,
    "11:15" => 40,
    "11:30" => 40
    "13:30" = >35,
    "14:00" => 40,
    "15:00" => 40
     },
   [1] {
    "12:00" => 38,
    "12:45" => 39,
    "13:00" => 39,
    "13:15" => 39,
    "13:30" => 39
    }
]
```

I need to get this new filtered array:

```
 [
   [0] {
    "10:45" => 40,
    "13:30" = >35,
    "14:00" => 40
     },
   [1] {
    "12:00" => 38,
    "12:45" => 39
    }
]
```

In other words "delete key/value if value equals to right before value".

Comment: Great, what's your question?

Comment: you'll most probably get answers on how to do that but you should at least try to solve it first then let us know where you're having trouble.

Comment: I have tried to do this but it doesn't work: `array.map do |elem|
      value = 0
      elem.delete_if { |k, v| v == value; value = v; }
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this, you have this array

```
array = [
   {
    "10:45" => 40,
    "11:00" => 40,
    "11:15" => 40,
    "11:30" => 40,
    "13:30" = >35,
    "14:00" => 40,
    "15:00" => 40
   },
   {
    "12:00" => 38,
    "12:45" => 39,
    "13:00" => 39,
    "13:15" => 39,
    "13:30" => 39
   }
]
```

Let's remove the duplicate values

```
def get_results(array)
  final_array = []

  array.each do |hash|
    final_hash = {}

    hash.each do |key, value|
      final_hash[key] = value unless final_hash.values.last == value
    end
    final_array << final_hash
  end
  final_array
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Answer is `[{"10:45"=>40, "13:30"=>35}, {"12:00"=>38, "12:45"=>39}]`    It have lost `"14:00" => 40`

Comment: Oops, I have edited the answer, try it again